# How to get the PromiseValue of the return value of tf.toPixels() in tensorflowjs

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

[image]

As shown in the figure, is the output obtained using console.log(tf.toPixels()). How can I get the Uint8ClampedArray array in PromiseValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `.then(callback)`, where callback is a function and gets the resolved `Uint8ClampedArray` as the argument.

Or if you are in an async environment, you can simply use `await`:

```
async function run(){
    const pixels = await tf.toPixels();
}
```

Comment: How can I use ".then(callback) "to get the data?

Comment: callback is a function you create and it gets called with the resolve value as the parameter

Comment: The wait time for “ then” function and the await function is the same？

Comment: Yes, they both run in the tick, the promise resolves